# Issue with diagrams in sql management studio 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-diagrams

I have this issue with sql management studio 2014.

When creating a new database diagram and when I add existing table to a new diagram, the data inside a table is obsolete. I tried both dragging a table from list of tables and refreshing a table listing when using "Add table" function, but the result is the same.
I have noticed this when I expand column list in object explorer, the actual columns are different then the columns of same table inside a diagram.

Did anyone experience the same problem, and how do I avoid this issue since it is very annoying and caused me a lot of unnecessary problems? If nothing else, I will have to try with a new version.

Comment: Any reason not using [latest SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) 17.6?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of this? Is it possible you have tables with the same name in different schemas, different databases, or on different servers? Is the column list different, or incomplete (maybe you have been denied access to some columns)? Are you using SQL Server Express and user instances / attachdbfilename? Diagrams get their information from the metadata - there is no cached / obsolete version for it to see.